# no sé que está mal en este codigo,

Tags: ejecutar

```
Escribir "ejecutando"

escribir "|----------------------------------------|";
escribir "               Bienvenido"
escribir "|----------------------------------------|";
Escribir "Para adquirir su  ticket proporcione los  "
escribir "siguientes datos:                         "
escribir Sin Saltar "Fecha: (DD - MM - AA)"
leer fec
Escribir Sin Saltar "Nombre:"
Leer nom
escribir sin saltar "Edad:"
leer ed
escribir "Selecciona la pelicula (1-4)" 
escribir "1) Depredador "
Escribir "2) Los pitufos "
escribir "3) Blanca nieves "
Escribir "4) Super 8 "
leer pell

Si pell > 0 y pell <= 4 Entonces
    Escribir "Selecciona la sala"
    escribir "1) sala 1"
    escribir "2) sala 2"
    escribir "3) sala 3"
    leer room
    Si room > 0 y room <= 3 Entonces
        Escribir "Seleciona el tipo de proyeccion "
        Escribir "1) 2D"
        escribir "2) 3D"
        escribir "3) 5D"
        Leer expp
        Si expp < 0 y expp <= 3 Entonces
            escribir "Elija la jornada"
            escribir "1) Lunes a viernes "
            escribir "2) Fin de semana"
            leer jorn
            Segun jorn Hacer
                1:
                    Escribir "Indique el día "
                    Escribir "1) Lunes "
                    Escribir "2) Martes "
                    Escribir "3) Miercoles "
                    Escribir "4) Jueves "
                    escribir "5) Viernes "
                    Leer dia
                    si dia > 0 y dia <= 5 Entonces
                        escribir "Elija la hora a la que desea asistir "
                        escribir "1) 3:00pm - 5:00pm "
                        escribir "2) 5:00pm - 7:00pm "
                        escribir "3) 7:00pm - 9_00pm "
                        leer hour
                        si hour > 0  y hour <= 3 Entonces
                            Escribir "¿Cuenta con tarjeta Cinemax? "
                            escribir "1) Si "
                            escribir "2) No "
                        sino 
                            Escribir "Error, posible opción no valida"
                        FinSi
                    SiNo
                        Escribir "Error, posible opción no valida"
                    FinSi
                    
                2:
                    Escribir "Indique el dia "
                    Escribir "!) Sabado "
                    escribir "2) Domingo"
                    leer dia
                    si dia > 0 y dia <= 2 Entonces
                        escribir "Elija la hora a la que desea asistir "
                        escribir "1) 4:00pm - 6:00pm "
                        escribir "2) 6:00pm _ 8:00pm "
                        escribir "3) 8:00pm - 10:00pm "
                        leer hour
                        si hour > 0  y hour <= 3 Entonces
                            Escribir "¿Cuenta con tarjeta Cinemax? "
                            escribir "1) Si "
                            escribir "2) No "
                            
                        SiNo
                            Escribir "Error, posible opción no valida"
                        FinSi
                        
                    SiNo
                        Escribir "Error, posible opción no valida"
                    FinSi
                    
            De Otro Modo
                  Escribir "Opción no valida"
                    
            Fin Segun
            
        SiNo
            Escribir "Error, posible opción no valida"
        Fin Si
        
    SiNo
        Escribir "Error, posible opción no valida"
    Fin Si
    
SiNo
    Escribir "Error, posible opción no valida"
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Pon en el título de la pregunta el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. 2. Pon en las etiquetas con qué lenguaje estás trabajando. 3. ¡No coloques solo código! Explica el enunciado y el problema en cuestión.

Comment: Ese lenguaje es pseint?

Answer (score 1):

> Escribir "Indique el dia "
> Escribir "!) Sabado "
> escribir "2) Domingo"
> leer dia

Tienes un signo de exclamación en vez de un 1.